# How to use Hickory with Clojurescript (OM/Reagent)?

Tags: clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, hiccup, om

In my Reagent project, I'm parsing HTML with Hickory and rendering a Hiccup page. The hiccup is rendered. But when I change the page (*!reset my view atom*), React.js goes crazy because Hickory has generated:

`[:div (as-hiccup (parse "<h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>"))]`

`=> ([:html {} [:head {}] [:body {} [:h1 {} HELLO WORLD!]]])`

As you can see, it has generated `<html>` `<head>` `<body>` tags which I think is causing Reactjs to blow up because my view already have those tags. Ideally, I want it to only generate `[:h1 {} HELLO WORLD!]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(map as-hiccup (parse-fragment "<h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>"))`

generates `[:h1 "HELLO WORLD!"]`